# JSON to DataFrames in Python3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON data as below in list. Each line is a independent dictionary

```py
["{'asin': '0001048791', 'salesRank': {'Books': 6334800}, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4DBL.jpg', 'categories': [['Books']], 'title': 'The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jerome Dempsey &amp; Cast'}\n",
 "{'asin': '0000143561', 'categories': [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']], 'description': '3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and Holidays.', 'title': 'Everyday Italian (with Giada de Laurentiis), Volume 1 (3 Pack): Italian Classics, Parties, Holidays', 'price': 12.99, 'salesRank': {'Movies & TV': 376041}, 'imUrl': 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-site/icons/no-img-sm._CB192198896_.gif', *'related'*: {'also_viewed': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC', 'B002I5GNVU', 'B000RBU4BM'], 'buy_after_viewing': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC']}}\n"]
```

If you look at the data carefully, you can observe the below

1. The key `related` / `also_bought` / `also_viewed` is intermittently available
2. it has `\n` after each pair of `{}`.

Below is the maximum columns that this data can contain.
[Max columns that a single dict in the each line of file can contain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF5Ip.png)

My ultimate goal is to move the above instructed columns data to the data frame and am not sure whether i can move it or not.

Kindly help!

Comment: Welcome on board! Could you please clarify what do you mean by "intermittently available". Also what kind of DataFrames you mentioned? Pandas? If so could you add appropriate tag for it?

Comment: Question: How did you obtain these strings? Whatever you are trying to do would be made a lot easier if instead of reading your JSON in as a string you deserialized it (either using `json` or `pandas` libraries).

Comment: You are probably getting this from a file. I am guessing this because of the trailing "\n". Also, it is easy to get this into a DataFrame, and intermittently available keys are not a problem as those cells will be filled with NaN. The point is that if you are reading a file into a JSON, chances are it will be easier if it is directly read into a DataFrame. If not, a bit of string manipulation will give a final JSON object which can be converted to a DataFrame. Please let us know if this comes from a file.

Comment: Hi vsminkov ... i meant, i read this data from a .json file. after reading each record/line is in dictionary format. yes.. i would like to move that to pandas dataframes

Comment: Hi Juanpa.. i dowloaded .json file from a website.. and this is how it is coming

Comment: Hi Karthik.. i think you are almost near to my thoughts.. I tried to get into dataframes directly. but i get some value error due to unstructured string. i tried to clean it. i am stuck at a place where i have to loop through each record in the file and append to a dictionary and then convert that to dataframe.   can you please help or share the code if you have which meets the above scenario of data structure..

Comment: @ShruthiAdarsha So you read each a JSON file, line by line (e.g. using f`.readlines()` ? What you have is not valid JSON. Can you share the code you used to get that list?

Answer (score 0):

### Your Data is not JSON

OK - There are several issues with what you are attempting to do. First, just copying and pasting your list into an interactive interpreter session:

```
>>> data = ["{'asin': '0001048791', 'salesRank': {'Books': 6334800}, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4DBL.jpg', 'categories': [['Books']], 'title': 'The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jerome Dempsey &amp; Cast'}\n",
...  "{'asin': '0000143561', 'categories': [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']], 'description': '3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and Holidays.', 'title': 'Everyday Italian (with Giada de Laurentiis), Volume 1 (3 Pack): Italian Classics, Parties, Holidays', 'price': 12.99, 'salesRank': {'Movies & TV': 376041}, 'imUrl': 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-site/icons/no-img-sm._CB192198896_.gif', *'related'*: {'also_viewed': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC', 'B002I5GNVU', 'B000RBU4BM'], 'buy_after_viewing': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC']}}\n"]
>>> [type(x) for x in data]
[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
```

You simply have a list with two strings. These are not dictionaries, and more importantly, they are not valid JSON. Notice that the strings have single-quotes and that there are keys like this:

```
*'related'*: {'also_viewed': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC', 'B002I5GNVU', 'B000RBU4BM'], 'buy_after_viewing': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC']}
```

With two asterisks (*) surrounding it *outside* the single-quotes. This is certainly not valid JSON. At first, my suspicion was that you read the data in using code like the following:

```
with open('data.json','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

That would imply that your .json file was invalid to begin with. However, th screenshot you posted shows valid json code, so whatever processing you did turned a valid json file into strings which are invalid as JSON. For the example you gave, we can do a quick hack to turn these into valid Python objects by using the `json` module function `loads` which deserializes a valid JSON string into Python objects:

```
>>> import json
>>> valid_data = [json.loads(s.replace("'",'"').replace('*','')) for s in data]
```

Notice that for each string in my original list, I replace single-quotes (`'`) with double-quotes (`"`) and remove asterisks (`*`). Now, this is what you want:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(valid_data)
[{'asin': '0001048791',
  'categories': [['Books']],
  'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4DBL.jpg',
  'salesRank': {'Books': 6334800},
  'title': 'The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jerome Dempsey &amp; '
           'Cast'},
 {'asin': '0000143561',
  'categories': [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']],
  'description': '3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and Holidays.',
  'imUrl': 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-site/icons/no-img-sm._CB192198896_.gif',
  'price': 12.99,
  'related': {'also_viewed': ['B0036FO6SI',
                              'B000KL8ODE',
                              '000014357X',
                              'B0037718RC',
                              'B002I5GNVU',
                              'B000RBU4BM'],
              'buy_after_viewing': ['B0036FO6SI',
                                    'B000KL8ODE',
                                    '000014357X',
                                    'B0037718RC']},
  'salesRank': {'Movies & TV': 376041},
  'title': 'Everyday Italian (with Giada de Laurentiis), Volume 1 (3 Pack): '
           'Italian Classics, Parties, Holidays'}]
```

Now, you can simply use the `DataFrame` constructor from `pandas`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(valid_data)
>>> df
         asin               categories  \
0  0001048791                [[Books]]   
1  0000143561  [[Movies & TV, Movies]]   

                                         description  \
0                                                NaN   
1  3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and ...   

                                               imUrl  price  \
0  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4...    NaN   
1  http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-s...  12.99   

                                             related                salesRank  \
0                                                NaN       {'Books': 6334800}   
1  {'also_viewed': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '...  {'Movies & TV': 376041}   

                                               title  
0  The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jero...  
1  Everyday Italian (with Giada de Laurentiis), V...  
>>> data[0]
"{'asin': '0001048791', 'salesRank': {'Books': 6334800}, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4DBL.jpg', 'categories': [['Books']], 'title': 'The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jerome Dempsey &amp; Cast'}\n"
>>> df['asin']
0    0001048791
1    0000143561
Name: asin, dtype: object
>>> df.columns
Index(['asin', 'categories', 'description', 'imUrl', 'price', 'related',
       'salesRank', 'title'],
      dtype='object')
```

That worked, and as you can see, it dealt with the intermittent values for certain columns by filling in with `NaN`. Some of these columns, like `'related'` simply store dictionaries. This might not be what you want, really, but from this point you must decide how exactly you want to clean up or reshape this data. If you run into issues there, it might be worth starting another question.

### Finally

Instead of hacking away at the data after it has been turned into these strings, you might just want to do the following (let's say the file you are working with is called 'data.json'):

```
>>> with open('valid_json.json') as f:
...    data = pd.read_json(f)
... 
>>> data
      asin               categories  \
0  1048791                [[Books]]   
1   143561  [[Movies & TV, Movies]]   

                                         description  \
0                                                NaN   
1  3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and ...   

                                               imUrl  price  \
0  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4...    NaN   
1  http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-s...  12.99   

                                             related                salesRank  \
0                                                NaN       {'Books': 6334800}   
1  {'also_viewed': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '...  {'Movies & TV': 376041}   

                                               title  
0  The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jero...  
1  Everyday Italian (with Giada de Laurentiis), V...  
>>> type(data)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: excellent juanpa.. i had that impression that this json is not a valid.. since i am struggling much to get it right. let me use your suggestion and get back to you.. thanks for all your time in getting this out of the blues:)